# DCM/DFA reporting api and refresh tokens

Tags: google-oauth

In the [Google OAuth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

under refresh tokens it says:

> 4. **Refresh the access token, if necessary.**
>
> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

How do I know if this use case applies to my app?

I'm accessing DCM/DFA data and am unsure if I need to worry about refreshing an access token.

EDIT FOR pinoyyid

pinoyyid mentions the refresh token.

In the DCM sample app, this code (com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp)

```
public Credential authorize(String userId) throws IOException {
try {
  Credential credential = flow.loadCredential(userId);
  if (credential != null
      && (credential.getRefreshToken() != null || 
          credential.getExpiresInSeconds() == null || 
          credential.getExpiresInSeconds() > 60)) {
    return credential;
  }
  // open in browser
  String redirectUri = receiver.getRedirectUri();
```

seems to say as long as you have a non null refresh token you are authenticated.

I was able to replace my refresh token with a garbage string and still get access.

That seems, wrong somehow. Is there some way to verify the refresh token or is it unnecessary?

FINAL EDIT FOR pinoyyid:

I think I got it.  I'd like to confirm this is the right interpretation of what's going on.

My first clue was the part of the docs (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) that said

"If you use a Google API Client Library, the client object refreshes the access token as needed as long as you configure that object for offline access."

I am using the following:

google-oauth-client 1.24.1
google-oauth-client-java6 1.24.1
google-oauth-client-jetty 1.24.1

When I run with a completely invalid access token ("i am no good") and a valid refresh token and execute a
DCM API call to a com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient subclass, I observe the following behavior:

control passes to com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential at method:

```
  public final boolean refreshToken() throws IOException {
lock.lock();
try {
  try {
    TokenResponse tokenResponse = executeRefreshToken();
    if (tokenResponse != null) {
      setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
      for (CredentialRefreshListener refreshListener : refreshListeners) {
        refreshListener.onTokenResponse(this, tokenResponse);
      }
      return true;
    }
  } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
    boolean statusCode4xx = 400 <= e.getStatusCode() && e.getStatusCode() < 500;
    // check if it is a normal error response
    if (e.getDetails() != null && statusCode4xx) {
      // We were unable to get a new access token (e.g. it may have been revoked), we must now
      // indicate that our current token is invalid.
      setAccessToken(null);
      setExpiresInSeconds(null);
    }
    for (CredentialRefreshListener refreshListener : refreshListeners) {
      refreshListener.onTokenErrorResponse(this, e.getDetails());
    }
    if (statusCode4xx) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
  return false;
} finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

}

this goes out and gets a new access token as long as the refresh token is valid (i've tried using an invalid refresh token and watched it fail).

Upon successful retrieval of a new access token, control passes to

```
refreshListener.onTokenErrorResponse(this, e.getDetails());
```

The token is inserted into the proper objects and access continues.

If I run with a bad refresh token the above method fails with:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: The access token expires after 1 hour. If that causes your app a problem, then you either need to re-prompt for authorization, or request offline access (= refresh token), which you can store and then use to create fresh access tokens.

Comment: pinoyyid - thank you for your answer.  based on some further observation, i've added an additional question.

Comment: access is granted using the Access Token, so if you only garbage out the Refresh Token, you still have a valid Access Token. To test if your Refresh Token is valid, try using it to request an Access Token as described at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: pinoyyid - thank you again.  based on your response i did some additional research and i think i got it figured out!  i've edited my original question and added my findings.  can you please look at them and let me know if i've got the right idea?

Comment: You may well be correct, but unfortunately I am the world's biggest OAuth library anti-fan. OAuth isn't that difficult to understand, but the Google libraries do such a great job of obfuscating what is happening under the covers that I gave up on them a long time ago.

Comment: anti-fan.  i like that!  very apropos.  i certain understand the sentiment and i agree with you completely.  i'll make another post and see it gets any traction.  THANK YOU very much for your help.